# Week list not give me correct out put

Tags: android, flutter, dart

My code :

1. Select  24 date
2. they print 31/07 - 31/07
3. not print  like this  31/07 - 06/08

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class WeekList extends StatefulWidget {
  const WeekList({super.key});

  @override
  State<WeekList> createState() => _WeekListState();
}

class _WeekListState extends State<WeekList> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    DateTime currentDate = DateTime.now();
    DateTime startOfWeek = getStartOfWeek(currentDate);

    List<String> weekDateRange = generateWeekDateRange(startOfWeek, 5); // 5 weeks display karein

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Date Range List'),
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: weekDateRange.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            String dateRange = weekDateRange[index];
            bool isSelected = isDateRangeSelected(dateRange, currentDate);
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(
                dateRange,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: isSelected ? FontWeight.bold : FontWeight.normal,
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

DateTime getStartOfWeek(DateTime date) {
  return date.subtract(Duration(days: date.weekday - 1));
}

List<String> generateWeekDateRange(DateTime startOfWeek, int numberOfWeeks) {
  List<String> weekList = [];
  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfWeeks; i++) {
    DateTime endDate = startOfWeek.add(const Duration(days: 6));

    if (endDate.day <= 7) {
      // Check if endDate is on or before the 7th day of the month
      DateTime nextMonth = DateTime(startOfWeek.year, startOfWeek.month + 1, 1);
      endDate = nextMonth.subtract(const Duration(days: 1));
    }

    if (endDate.isAfter(DateTime(startOfWeek.year, startOfWeek.month, startOfWeek.day + 6))) {
      // Check if endDate is in the next month
      endDate = DateTime(startOfWeek.year, startOfWeek.month, startOfWeek.day + 6);
    }

    String formattedDateRange =
        '${DateFormat('dd/MM').format(startOfWeek)} - ${DateFormat('dd/MM').format(endDate)}';
    weekList.add(formattedDateRange);

    // Move the startOfWeek to the next week
    startOfWeek = endDate.add(const Duration(days: 1));
  }
  return weekList;
}

bool isDateRangeSelected(String dateRange, DateTime currentDate) {
  List<String> parts = dateRange.split(' - ');
  DateTime startDate = DateFormat('dd/MM').parse(parts[0]);
  DateTime endDate = DateFormat('dd/MM').parse(parts[1]);
  return currentDate.isAfter(startDate) && currentDate.isBefore(endDate.add(const Duration(days: 1)));
}
```

Current output:

```
I/flutter (30371): 01/08 - 07/08
I/flutter (30371): 08/08 - 14/08
I/flutter (30371): 15/08 - 21/08
I/flutter (30371): 24/07 - 30/07
I/flutter (30371): 31/07 - 31/07
```

i want to print like this:

```
24/07 - 30-07  
31/07 -  06/08  
07/08 - 13/08  
14/08 - 20/08
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely hit into the issue of handling daylight summer time (DST). `DateTime` in Dart are default your local timezone which often have the concept of DST. When you use `add`/`sub` on `DateTime`, you provide a `Duration` object which converts all units into e.g. milliseconds. So when adding days, it will convert each day to 24 hour and so on.

But because DST allows days to be sometimes 25 hours and 23 hours long, the adding of days in Dart does often give these problems.

The solution is often to use UTC as timezone instead since this is a fixed timezone without DST. So when you want current time, use `DateTime.timestamp()` instead to get a UTC version of `DateTime`. And when you create new `DateTime` objects, make sure to use the `DateTime.utc()` constructor instead of `DateTime`.

Read more about this in the documentation of `DateTime`: https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.0.6/dart-core/DateTime-class.html

I can also see your `generateWeekDateRange` method are a lot more complicated than needed for the output you want.

Example of how I think your code could be fixed where I have also simplified `generateWeekDateRange`. I don't use Flutter myself so I have not tested it:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class WeekList extends StatefulWidget {
  const WeekList({super.key});

  @override
  State<WeekList> createState() => _WeekListState();
}

class _WeekListState extends State<WeekList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    DateTime currentDate = DateTime.timestamp();
    DateTime startOfWeek = getStartOfWeek(currentDate);

    List<String> weekDateRange =
        generateWeekDateRange(startOfWeek, 5); // 5 weeks display karein

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Date Range List'),
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: weekDateRange.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            String dateRange = weekDateRange[index];
            bool isSelected = isDateRangeSelected(dateRange, currentDate);
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(
                dateRange,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: isSelected ? FontWeight.bold : FontWeight.normal,
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

DateTime getStartOfWeek(DateTime date) {
  return date.subtract(Duration(days: date.weekday - 1));
}

List<String> generateWeekDateRange(DateTime startOfWeek, int numberOfWeeks) {
  List<String> weekList = [];
  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfWeeks; i++) {
    DateTime endDate = startOfWeek.add(const Duration(days: 6));

    String formattedDateRange =
        '${DateFormat('dd/MM').format(startOfWeek)} - ${DateFormat('dd/MM').format(endDate)}';
    weekList.add(formattedDateRange);

    // Move the startOfWeek to the next week
    startOfWeek = endDate.add(const Duration(days: 1));
  }
  return weekList;
}

bool isDateRangeSelected(String dateRange, DateTime currentDate) {
  List<String> parts = dateRange.split(' - ');
  DateTime startDate = DateFormat('dd/MM').parseUtc(parts[0]);
  DateTime endDate = DateFormat('dd/MM').parseUtc(parts[1]);
  return currentDate.isAfter(startDate) &&
      currentDate.isBefore(endDate.add(const Duration(days: 1)));
}
```

Comment: Can you give me code

Comment: @HardikSindhav Found some issues related to your `generateWeekDateRange` method. I have cleaned it up and tried run the solution on DartPad.dev where it now looks like it outputs the result you want: https://dartpad.dev/?id=47286a168eac2026d01e7252faf6eff6